# Change pivot point of object in RealityKit

Tags: swift, xcode, pivot, augmented-reality, realitykit

I want a cube to be scaled only over the positive z-axis.
Now when I scale it, it's always scaled around its center. So for this I will have to change the anchor point of the object.

I know in SceneKit there was a pivot property you could use.

Is there a way to do this in RealityKit too?

Answer (score 4):

I found a fairly easy way to replicate the *pivot* functionality from SceneKit, in RealityKit.

All you need to do is wrap your **ModelEntity** within another outer "parent" **Entity** and offset the inner **ModelEntity** by the desired *pivot* value (SIMD3<Float>).

Once you've done that, you can position or rotate the outer "parent" entity and the inner entity will behave in essentially the same way as a SceneKit SCNNode with a *pivot* value applied.

Comment: Can you show us some code perhaps please paul?

Answer (score 3):

#### iOS RealityKit

Pity, but in RealityKit framework you have no possibility to explicitly define model's pivot point's position. Hence, the best solution is to set pivot in 3D authoring app (like Maya or Blender).

However, when prototyping a scene in iOS Reality Composer, `Orbit` behavior allows you automatically position model's pivot in the center of another model.

Also, there's a similar implicit-pivot-positioning approach in RealityKit 2.0 when working with `move(...)` methods. Use `relativeTo` parameter to define pivot's position at the world origin (`nil`) or at a center of another model (`entity`), to commit a transform animation.

Or you can place a model inside an empty group (Entity) or [AnchorEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258882/realitykit-scale-a-model-from-its-center/76259984#76259984), and you'll get 2 independent pivots.

#### visionOS RealityKit

In visionOS, you can use SwiftUI's `.scaleEffect(x:y:z:anchor:)` modifier with `anchor` parameter to scale the whole view about chosen axis (pivot point position). The tap gesture works only when Collision and InputTarget components are assigned.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scaleCoef: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Model3D(named: "Scene", bundle: realityKitContentBundle)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1.0)) {
                    scaleCoef += 1.0
                }
            }
            .scaleEffect(x: scaleCoef, 
                         y: scaleCoef, 
                         z: scaleCoef, anchor: .topFront)
    }
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: So when I make a cube myself in code, there's no way to change the pivot point? I think it's weird there was a way in SceneKit but not in RealityKit

Comment: At the moment – no. API is too young. Let's wait for an update of RealityKit, I'm sure there are many tools will be added.

Comment: For visionOS, is there any API for Entity to do this？