# RealityKit – Updating Entity's translation returns unexpected values

Tags: swift, realitykit

This little method that I wrote, changes spotlight1's position to the unexpected value.

If I understand well, setPosition method should set spotlight's translation relative to the tv's position

TV's translation: [0.0, 0.0, -5.0]
setPosition to [0.0, 5.0, 0.5] relative to Tv's translation.

So:

```
[0.0 + 0, 0.0 + 5, -5.0 + 0.5] = [0.0, 5.0, -4.5]
```

But what I get is:

```
[0.0, 0.9999994, -4.9]
```

Am I missing some important information here?

```
func loadLights() {
    arView.scene.addAnchor(lightAnchor)
    lightAnchor.addChild(spotlight1)
    print(tv?.position)             // 0.0, 0.0, -5.0
    spotlight1.setPosition([0, 5, 0.5], relativeTo: tv)

    if let tv = tv {
        spotlight1.look(at: tv.position, 
                      from: spotlight1.position, 
                relativeTo: nil)
    }        
    print(spotlight1.position)     // 0.0, 0.99999994, -4.99
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Reference Coordinate Frame

As paradoxical as it may sound, RealityKit did everything right. You need to take into account the [frame of reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/3244121-setposition) (frame of your `tv` model). As far as I understand, you reduced the scale of the `tv` model by five times. Am I right? However, reference's transform matters.

In other words, you've scaled down the local coordinate frame (a.k.a. local coordinate system) of the TV model, you're trying to position `spotLight1` relative to.

### About `relativeTo` parameter

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72267172/realitykit-rotating-an-entity-affects-its-scale/72267314#72267314) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336650/change-pivot-point-of-object-in-realitykit/59338047#59338047) to explore possible issues.

Comment: Hey Andy. Not sure if I follow. I did not want to reduce tv's scale 5 times. My intention was to:

Comment: That's why it's a good practice to put ModelEntity inside Entity to separate two transforms. :)

Comment: Sorry, it seems that it cut a part of my comment..

Comment: Are we talking about creating a subclass of entity "TV", and assigning a model to it? Or create a nested 'tv' variable within that new subclass, and then assigning that entity there? And after that, which translation is the best practise to modify? Thanks!

Comment: You need to put a nested model inside an empty entity (`entity.addChild(model)`). Entity is like a container for your model.