# How can I move a model using facial expression like look-right?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have set a virtual object in rear camera view. I want to move that object using facial expression with respect to world origin and measure the displacement angles of the virtual object.

Is that possible using ARKit or RealityKit?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following solution. At first setup a configuration:

```
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        arView.session.delegate = self
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
       
        let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        config.isWorldTrackingEnabled = true        // Simultaneous tracking
        arView.session.run(config)
    }
}
```

Run your [transform animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72746376/entity-disappears-at-the-end-of-the-animation) when a defined facial expression occurs:

```
func facialExpression(anchor: ARFaceAnchor) {
    
    let eyeUpLeft = anchor.blendShapes[.eyeLookUpLeft]
    let eyeUpRight = anchor.blendShapes[.eyeLookUpRight]

    if ((eyeUpLeft?.decimalValue ?? 0.0) + 
        (eyeUpRight?.decimalValue ?? 0.0)) > 0.75 {

        // ModelEntity's animation goes here
    }
}
```

Delegate's method (running at 60 fps):

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

    guard let faceAnchor = anchors[0] as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }
    self.facialExpression(anchor: faceAnchor)
}
```

The answer to your second question you can see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217885/how-can-i-measure-displacement-angle-of-a-virtual-object-from-world-origin/73235357#73235357).

Comment: Can I measure the displacement angle of the moving object(which I am moving using facial expression) from world origin?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I mentioned that in my description. Its relative to world origin.

Comment: Please let me know if I still have to through a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mr. Andy, I have put the separate question. Can you please have a look? Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217885/how-can-i-measure-displacement-angle-of-a-virtual-object-from-world-origin-using

Comment: In the beginning of ARSession, the Model will be fixed at the center point of world origin. Then user can move the model using eye-ball movement(right,left,up,down). I want to track this displacement of model/ velocity of the model with respect to world origin.